# Cucumber (Java) and Selenium: where to place driver path using setProperty?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm building a test suite using Cucumber for Java with Selenium. And my project structure is pretty much like this:

- src/test/java: this is where I have my test steps implementation.
- src/test/resources/features: this is where I have feature files.
- src/test/resources/seleniumdrivers: this is where I put chromedriver.exe.

Now, what I did was to add a Hooks.java class in src/test/java with a method that sets up the driver path, using the @Before hook:

```
@Before
public void setUpDriver(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src\\test\\resources\\seleniumdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
}
```

However, since this method will run before each scenario, I'd like to find a better way to set up the path, so it's only done once. Please note that I want to have the driver within my project structure and set it using a system property (I mean, I don't want to place the driver somewhere in my filesystem and add it to the PATH environment variable).

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use a static flag in the hooks class to run once or use BeforeClass (BeforeAll for junit5) in runner class. Refer to this -- https://automationpanda.com/2017/03/03/cucumber-jvm-global-hook-workarounds/

Comment: Do you wan to set the driver path before all scenarios or do you want to launch browser only once(i.e before first scenario)

Comment: @Grasshopper the problem is, `@BeforeAll` is not available for the Java implementation of Cucumber (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770103/global-beforeall-hook-for-cucumber-jvm). But the static flag sounds like a good idea, thanks!

Comment: @Pradeep this is about setting the driver path. Then I'll open the browser whenever it's needed, but I feel like the path needs to be set only once.

Comment: Have a look at my answer. It might solve your problem.

Comment: @Floella I am talking of the BeforeAll annotation of junit https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations not cucumber ruby. This will go into the cucumber runner class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one property file like `config.properties` to store all the global values which you use throughout the execution and also path of the `chromedriver.exe` and read it before all scenarios and use throughout the executions like this.

```
public class Hooks {
    private static boolean beforeSuit = true;
    private static String executablePath;
    static Properties prop;

    @Before
    public void beforeAll() {
        if(beforeSuit) {
            prop = new Properties();
            ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();           
            InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
            prop.load(stream);
            //You can use this anywhere you want to launch the chrome.
            executablePath = prop.getProperty("executablePath");
            //To make it execute only once
            beforeSuit = false;

            //If you wish to launch browser only once , you can have that code here.
        }

        //Here you can keep code to be execute before each scenario

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I actually did it a bit shorter than your proposed answer, but it follows the same idea. I added a boolean attribute in my class and then, in the `@before` method: `if(beforeSuit) { System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src\\test\\resources\\seleniumdrivers\\chromedriver.exe"); beforeSuit = false; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can keep driver inside your project folder and get that project path using `System.getProperty`

You can try below code :-

```
 String path= System.getProperty("user.dir");

  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path+"\\src\\test\\resources\\test\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: Right, but where should I put this? As I did something very similar to what you suggest, but I'm not happy with it being in the @Before hook. I mean, it works, but it doesn't look like a good practise. I'm trying to implement it the best way possible.

Answer (score 0):

As you *don't want to add it to the PATH environment variable* you can place the *chromedriver* binary **anywhere** within your filesystem (including `src\\test\\resources\\seleniumdrivers\\`) and still can specify in the `System.setProperty()` as follows :

```
@Before
public void setUpDriver(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".\\src\\test\\resources\\seleniumdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
}
```

Comment: Right, but that's exactly what I did. My problem is: this @Before hook will run **before each test**, which is not ideal. I want to set the driver path only once, before the whole suite runs.

Comment: Why do you feel  `is not ideal` ? As `@Before` hook will run **before each test** it will provide you the flexibility to choose between _ChromeDriver_ , _GeckoDriver_ and _IEDriverServer_ along with different versions kept in different sub-directories.

Comment: Yes, but this is setting up the driver path, not opening the browser. Then I'll add another hook to open whichever browser I need, but that's a different issue. I feel like I only have to tell my suite "you'll find the driver here" only once.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven add these 2 dependencies in your pom.xml and you will be fine and now you can remove the System.setProperty line. With this technique the project has less hardcode method.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Also you need to add this line to set it up

```
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```