# Set relative path for selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I create chrome driver like this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\ragnar_000\\IdeaProjects\\ProjectA\\src\\test\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
```

This code is written on Windows platform. When I run it on Mac, I have to edit the path according to Mac platform.

How to set/check the path so that it can run on all platforms, like it just needs the path src/test/resources/chromedrivers.exe

Comment: Ref this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853249/cucumber-java-and-selenium-where-to-place-driver-path-using-setproperty/48853340?noredirect=1#comment84710136_48853340

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a folder under your project and copy the chromedriver.exe to that folder (eg: /resources/chromedrivers.exe).

Then set the path to that folder by

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println(path); 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",path+"\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
```

I have tried in windows and its working.Try if it works on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways on answer to this question:
First: use absolute path.

```
Paths.get("." + File.separator + "folder" + File.separator + "chromedriver.exe"); //local project folder
Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "folder" + 
File.separator + "chromedriver.exe"); //file in folder in user home dircetory
```

That's very dublicate question. Googleit.

Second way: this setting need to store in project *.properties file and reload this propertie on file on every platform without rewrite test source code. Any path ended like "...driver.exe" is not aplicable on unix or mac. Also this way provide posability run tests with driver-path string.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // for firefox
```

or

```
WebDriver driver = new ChormeDriver(); // for chrome
```

should help resolve this issue.
Please ensure that you have imported the relevant classes

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
```